# Store Address Details for Customers & Orders

Tags: sql, database-design

I am struggling with the database design for storing customer address's and relating them to orders in an inventory system.  Currently I have the following schema ideas and 3 options:

**Customers**
CustomerID
CustomerName .....

**CustomerAddress**
AddressID
CustomerID
AddressType (Billing, Shipping etc)
AddressLine1
AddressLine2 
City
State
Country
PostCode

**Orders (Option 1)**
OrderID
CustomerID
BillingAddressID
ShippingAddressID

**Orders (Option 2)**
OrderID
CustomerID
BillingAddressLine1
BillingAddressLine2
BillingCity
BillingState
BillingCountry
BillingPostCode
ShippingAddressLine1
ShippingAddressLine2
ShippingCity
ShippingState
ShippingCountry
ShippingPostCode

**Orders (Option 3)**
OrderID
CustomerID
BillingAddressBlob
ShippingAddressBlob

I need the address for an order to remain static overtime.  So if I look back at an order two years ago I can see the correct address items were shipped too and billed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the answer since previous answer did not help the user.

You can have a table OrderAddress Table to save address

OrderAddress Table with following columns

- OrderId
- AddressId

To link Customer to Address you can have a table CustomerAddress with following columns

- CustomerId
- AddressId
- Street
- City
- PIN
- Phone
- State
- Isactive

Isactive column would be used to differentiate which address is currently active. Also, From this table you can see how many different addresses existed for a customer

To find the exact address where order was shipped you can check OrderAddress Table

Hope this soultions meets your need

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have already seen that website and the shemas you linked too.  Unfortunately they do not help as there is no link between orders and addresses in those schema.

Comment: Thanks Siva, could you explain why you are creating a seperate table for orderaddress.  As there can only ever be one shipping address and one billing address per order, why not just have the two addressid in the orders table - (option 1)?

Comment: - Order to Address is 1-1 mapping, Customer to Address can be 1 to Many Mapping. There can be more than 1 Address but only active address need to be present. When an Order is updated with New Address entry would get updated in OrderAddress Table. Rather in a CustomerAddress Table new entry will be added. Also, When you query records you might look for number of orders for a customer. You may not need address associated with a customer unless you need more details. This is based on query usage (My perspective)

Comment: I'm very sorry but I'm just not getting it.  I think I have developed a bit of a mind set. I just cant see the benefit in the extra table as opposed to storing the address ids in the orders table.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Right fresh mind this morning.  Would you mind explaining your idea once again please?

Comment: 1. Query Pattern (You might be checking how many orders per customer). Not in Every case you may need address. Unless customer wants to know full details of order. This is one reason i opted for OrderAddress Table 
2. Your requirement was to know exact address of customer for a paricular order. This you can obtain but getting AddressId from orderAddress and going to CustomerAddress for finding Address for it
4. CustomerAddress Can contain both Active and Inactive Address, You can partition it based on Active column (0,1).

Comment: 5. At any time you want to know active address query for isactive = 1 it would return you data
6. If you keep everything in one table, You might be loading everything in one table.
7. I do not think for finding orders submmitted by customer / orders for customer you need to know address about it
8. When you update address details, you will only update CustomerAddress Table

Comment: Thanks again Siva, that's clearer now.  However regarding point 8, if I edit a customers address then that will in turn affect all the previous orders which are linked to that address through the ordersaddress table. Or are you suggesting that I don't edit address's at all simply mark them as inactive?

Comment: No. OrderAddress is 1-1 Relationship. Each Order Can have 1 unique AddressId corresponding to the OrderAddress. If it is for same address use existing AddressId. If it is for a New Address, Create a New Address in CustomerAddress Table. You can have 3 values (1 - preferred Primary Address, 2 - Secondary Address, 3 - Old Address). Its upto you to decide on status value for tracking.

Comment: Lets say customer A has an address of 13A Mt Roskill Rd - addressID 1.  Now I create a new order (OrderID 5) and for that order I use the fore mentioned address.  So in orderaddress we have OrderID 5, AddressID 1.  Now the customer moves so the user then edits the address table and changes it to 13B Mt Roskill Road.  Now our address for our order is corrupt no?